# WSO2 Local Transport

Tags: wso2, local, transport, wso2-esb

I'm interested in understanding a little more about how local transport may aid performance within the WSO2 ESB.  I have looked at http://heshans.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/local-transport-implementation-for-wso2.html which suggests that the Proxy Services can communicate via local transport with the ***local*** prefix.  However, if a Web Application is also installed on the same ESB, is it possible to use local transport to communicate with the actual Web Service Endpoint?  The reason I ask is that I am investigating the differences in JBoss SOA in comparison with WSO2 and would like to understand if there are any performance advantages using JBoss over WSO2 as it appears that JBoss supports InVM transport.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the local transport is communicate efficiently with the services runs on the same JVM. For instance ESB proxy talking to another proxy service. You can use WSO2 Application Server to deploy web apps, but if you call it from another ESB instance then you cannot use local transport(because there are two jvms).

What you can do is that, you can install the WSO2 Application Server features on WSO2 ESB and then deploy the webapp. In that case you can use local transport between the webapp and esb proxy services etc.

Comment: Many thanks for your response.  I have installed the App Server features on the ESB and deployed the Webapp locally.  As you describe, it is possible for the esb proxies to talk to each other via local transport (see  http://heshans.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/local-transport-implementation-for-wso2.html).  However, the Web Service endpoint is still invoked via http not local?  Could you post some XML to show how you'd invoke the endpoint via local?  I tried replacing the 'http' for 'local' in the sample and that didn't work.   Any help on this would be very much appreciated!